# Group timestamps by hours

Tags: java

I have a List of Timestamps and want to group them to hours (24hours based)

Example:

```
List<Long> timestamps = new ArrayList<>();
//timestamps would contains 100 timestamps from over the last few days.

Now I want a map:
Map<String, List<Long>> groupedMap = new HashMap<>();

groupedMap would contain something like

{
   03.02.2015 - 12:00: [1234564321,1234564322,1234564323],
   03.02.2015 - 13:00: [12346664321,12346664323,12346664323]
}
```

I'm on Java 8. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the timestamps are unix second offsets from 1/1/1970, you could just bucket the timestamps by using the mod function:

```
long bucket = timestamp - (timestamp % 3600);
```

This removes whatever number of seconds past the hour are in any timestamp.

Comment: I don't want anything to be removed. Rather I'd like to group timestamps that are within an hour. As described in my question..

Comment: You're not removing anything, you're calculating the bucket to put the entry in. For for instance right now it's 10:45 here. If I want hour buckets, I want a bucket for 10:00 for that entry. The same bucket would have the entry for 10:50 and 10:01. Another bucket, 11:00, would contain the entry for 11:32.